# Java access dynamically created JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating an application which monitors a users desktop in Java. There are clients which are sending static images to the server and the server refreshes the dynamically created JFrame for that connection. I want to create a JFrame for every not existing connection.

```
package screensender;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ScreenSender extends Thread
{
       private ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
       private static Socket server = null;
       private Date date = null;
       private static final String DIR_NAME = "SACHIN";

       public ScreenSender() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception{
           serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1729);
           serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1800000);
       }

    public void run()
       {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Viewer");
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           JLabel message = new JLabel();
           JLabel wIcon = new JLabel();

           ArrayList<String> framecimek = new ArrayList<String>();

           while(true)
          {
               try
               {
                  server = serverSocket.accept();
                  date = new Date();
                      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("_yyMMdd_HHmmss");
                  String fileName = server.getInetAddress().getHostName().replace(".", "-");

                  BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
                  int width = img.getWidth();
                  int height = img.getHeight();

                  ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("C:\\CFEDITSNAPS\\"+fileName+".jpg"));

                  Frame[] allFrames = Frame.getFrames();

                    for(Frame fr : allFrames){

                        String specificFrameName = fr.getTitle();

                        if(!framecimek.contains(fileName))
                        {
                            framecimek.add(fileName);

                            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame(fileName);
                            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                            JLabel message2 = new JLabel();
                            JLabel wIcon2 = new JLabel();

                            frame2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width+15, height+39));
                            frame2.pack();
                            frame2.setVisible(true);

                            try {
                              img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\CFEDITSNAPS\\"+fileName+".jpg"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Image dimg2 = img.getScaledInstance(width, height,
                            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                            ImageIcon wPic2 = new ImageIcon(dimg2);

                            wIcon2.setIcon(wPic2);

                            frame2.remove(wIcon2);
                            frame2.add(wIcon2);
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame2);
                        } else if(framecimek.contains(fileName) && specificFrameName.equals(fileName))
                        {
                            fr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width+15, height+39));
                            fr.pack();
                            fr.setVisible(true);

                            try {
                              img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\CFEDITSNAPS\\"+fileName+".jpg"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(width, height,
                            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                            ImageIcon wPic = new ImageIcon(dimg);

                            wIcon.setIcon(wPic);

                            fr.remove(wIcon);
                            fr.add(wIcon);
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(fr);
                        }
                    }
              }
             catch(SocketTimeoutException st)
             {
                   System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                  break;
             }
             catch(IOException e)
             {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  break;
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
            {
                  System.out.println(ex);
            }
          }
       }

       public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception{
              ScreenSender serverApp = new ScreenSender();
              serverApp.createDirectory(DIR_NAME);
              Thread thread = new Thread(serverApp);
                thread.start();
       }

    private void createDirectory(String dirName) {
        File newDir = new File("C:\\"+dirName);
        if(!newDir.exists()){
            boolean isCreated = newDir.mkdir();
        }
     }
    }
```

The idea is that if the connection provides a non existing JFrame then I create it, but if it exists I only refresh it's content. The problem is that I cannot access the dynamically created JFrame with the `for(Frame fr : allFrames)` variable, but I need to replace it's image with the `wIcon` variable.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 3) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  ..

Comment: .. An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.